# Oauth2 Redirect URI for android application

Tags: android, rest, oauth, oauth-2.0, restlet

I have created my own webservice which is protected by Oauth2. I am currently using restlet for this. It makes sense providing a redirect url when you are developing a javascript client on a certain url, but what redirect uri do you provide when you are calling from a WebView.

I currently just make it redirect to localhost and register that to the oauth authorization server. Can anyone tell me if that is the correct way of handling this or am I getting this completely wrong? The redirect page can ofcourse not be found on the android device, but you can fetch the token from the url which was appended to the localhost url.

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Comment: I know a solution on flutter :/

Answer (score 3):

you can make your own URL schema and use it for redirect URL check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958701/launch-custom-android-application-from-android-browser) for customize your schema

Comment: As per info given on Google developer console, the schema should be only `http` or `https`.